# Content inside of div disappears when resizing browser

Tags: html, browser, resize

I'm having a problem with a website I've built: whenever I view the site on a smaller monitor or when I resize the browser window, the content gets covered by the other divs. I need the content to be fully visible, no matter what size the browser is.

http://sophisticateddesign.nl/cfreport/overons.html

Also, on the homepage the text gets cut off a little bit on the bottom row when I resize the browser. I need this row to increase in height a bit, which apparently can't be achieved by simply increasing the divs' height.

http://sophisticateddesign.nl/cfreport/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at responsive web design. By using a fluid grid together with one or many [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) you can achieve what you're asking for.

[Here's a good introduction](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-responsive-web-design) if you'd like to get started. I can also highly recommend [Ethan Marcotte's book](http://www.abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design) about the subject!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is not to define widths in pixels but using only width in %. You defined for example `width: 960px;` for `<html>` so if the browser window is less than 960px the whole content of this site won't be visible. You also defined the footer width and probably some more elements.

But the true is nowadays you should learn rather `Responsive Web Design` to create your page adjusting to device width. Many sites are being used by people on PC, laptops, tablets and mobile phones and you cannot create complex site to look nice on all those devices without using responsive design techniques.

Comment: Well, the thing is, it's a school project and I don't have much time left to learn about responsive design. The teacher is going to review the site on either a 13 or 15 inch monitor, so I think I shouldn't be worrying about anything smaller than that. Thank you for your advice though.